# find prestashop attribute by name with webservice

Tags: web-services, prestashop-1.6

To add an attribute or feature to a product by webservice, I need the id

To get the id for "red", I must first make a call to

```
get product_attribute_values?filter[id_category]=9 // 9 is colours
```

Then from that list I have to

```
get product_attribute_values/2
get product_attribute_values/4
get product_attribute_values/17
...
```

to get the names of each attribute_value (green,blue,red) until I find the value I want.

Is there no way to get attribute id by name?

I could do it easily in a join or two in mysql, but I am trying to do a clean import module to use only the webservice.

Because attributes like dimensions and weight are to be stored as an attribute or feature, even if the product schema contains dimensions and weight, the dimension and weight lists are rather large.

A work-around could be to just once scan the attribute/feature/options, and build a translate table in my import software.

Then when a product needs an attribute value, look it up in the cached table, perhaps verify if the tranlation text->id is still correct, and if not, rescan the attributes.

But can it be avoided?